# ? at the end of files in while listing file using 'ls'

Tags: shell, ls

While listing files using 'ls' command I get the following.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vineesh vineesh   2026 Nov 28 15:48 cdfg_ulit_89.txt?
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vineesh vineesh   1215 Nov 28 15:48 cdfg_ulit_8.txt?
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vineesh vineesh   1209 Nov 28 15:48 cdfg_ulit_90.txt?
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vineesh vineesh   3820 Nov 28 15:48 cdfg_ulit_9.txt?
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the output goes to a terminal devices, most `ls` implementations behave as if the `-q` option had been passed to them.

With `-q`, `ls` renders all non-printable characters as `?`

Here possibly, the non-printable character could be a carriage return character (aka CR aka `\r`). That could happen for instance if you ran `xargs touch < file.txt` and `file.txt` contained a list of file names but was using MS-DOS CR-LF line delimiters (and your `xargs` implementation like GNU `xargs` but unlike busybox `xargs` doesn't recognise CR as a separator).

It could also literally be a `?` character, it could even be a `?` followed by space or other invisible (but *printable*) characters.

To confirm which character it is, you can pipe that output to `LC_ALL=C sed -n l`.

```
ls -l | LC_ALL=C sed -n l
```

Then `ls` output will be a pipe (and so, no longer a terminal device) so won't enable `-q`. The non-printable characters will be output as is. `sed -n l` will render CR characters as `\r` and other non-printable characters using appropriate printable representations. It also adds a `$` at the end of the line so you can spot trailing space characters.

With the GNU implementation of `ls`, you can also use some of the `--quoting-style=<STYLE>` options, like:

```
LC_ALL=C ls --quoting-style=shell-escape -l
```

Or

```
LC_ALL=C ls -Ql
```

short for:

```
LC_ALL=C ls --quoting-style=c -l
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I was creating files using python and the filename had '\n' at the end. I used filename.strip() to remove the '\n'. Now the '?' vanished. Also the contents of the files came as expected (earlier the files were coming empty). Not sure if this is related to the filename issue.